# Error not count cliks when i add ajax code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When i add ajax code to save into server, it dosen't count my clicks.

I have 3 buttons each button means a type of error :

```
<button id="E1_<?= $c['code'] ?>">Type error 1</button>
<button id="E2_<?= $c['code'] ?>">Type error 2</button>
<button id="E3_<?= $c['code'] ?>">Type error 3</button>
```

This's my table :

```
  CREATE TABLE button_check
   (
      code varchar(255),
      button_1 int(11),
      button_2 int(11),
      button_3 int(11)
   );
```

Toggle Click function

```
$(function()
 {

 jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function(d,c){
    function cb(){ [d,c][this._tog^=1].call(this); }
    return this.on("click", cb);
 };

var all_errors = {'E1':0,'E2':0,'E3':0};

var btn1 = false;
btn2 = false;
btn3 = false;

  $("[id^='E1_']").clickToggle(function(){
    all_errors.E1++;
    console.log(all_errors);
},function(){
    if(all_errors .E1 > 0) all_errors .E1--;
});


    $("[id^='E2_']").clickToggle(function(){
    all_errors.E2++;
    console.log(all_errors);
},function(){
    if(all_errors .E2 > 0) all_errors .E2--;
});

 $("[id^='E3_']").clickToggle(function(){
    all_errors.E3++;
    console.log(all_errors);
},function(){
    if(all_errors .E3 > 0) all_errors .E3--;
});



  $.ajax({ url: 'data_insert.php',
   data: {id: value,value: all_errors},
   type: 'post',
   success: function(output) {
     console.log(output);
   }

});
```

data_insert.php :

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    try {      
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,  $password);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO button_check (code,button_1, button_2,button_3) VALUES ('$code','$btn1', 'btn2', 'btn3')";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    catch(PDOException $e)
     {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
     }
    }
```

[image: console output].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYvLH.jpg)
Please i need help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want to count each click in each button, your toogle function just will inscrease and decrease the attribute E1 in your JSON.

Comment: @JoseRojas yeah it shows me how many time i clicked in each button, i want to save a count of if each button in my database.

Comment: If I understand your issue well, you want to count the number of clicks in each button, this code that you have so far won't work because of I wrote more above, you only increment and decrement a variable and this only will be 1 and  0, your approach would have to change.

Comment: @JoseRojas yeah, i want to count each click of each button in my database. I added a picture of my results.

Comment: Do you know you have three buttons with the same id, right? and this can't simply be.

Comment: that code does not show the result as you have it in your last picture,  here https://jsfiddle.net/davideng14/dc8tzrq8/ your code running, please update your current code

Comment: Yeah normal, if you delete ajax code you will have a same result like in the picture.

Comment: @LelioFaieta yeah yeah  I have different id it just false modification data

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to recreate your situation and test it locally. The code for clickToggle is unecessary from what you've told us you want to do. Try this code:

**script.js**

```
$(function()
{
  var all_errors = {'E1':0,'E2':0,'E3':0};

    $("[id^='E1_']").click(function(){
        all_errors.E1++;
        console.log('errors', all_errors);
        $.ajax({ url: 'data_insert.php',
            data: {code: 1, btn1: all_errors.E1, btn2: all_errors.E2, btn3: all_errors.E3},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {
                console.log(output);
        }});
    });
});
```

This is code snippet for E1 button.

**data_insert.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

$code = $_POST['code'];
$btn1 = $_POST['btn1'];
$btn2 = $_POST['btn2'];
$btn3 = $_POST['btn3'];

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO button_check (code,button_1,button_2,button_3) VALUES ($code,$btn1,$btn2,$btn3)";
    $conn->exec($sql);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: it dosen't work. With my code it counts how many times I clicked on each button and declicked but when I add the ajax code it crashes I click but it shows me nothing.

Comment: what is the problem in your code? what error do you get? I thought that it doesn't count clicks at all.

Comment: I added a picture of my result without ajax code, when i click is 1 else 0.

Comment: so you want it to count clicks not to set them to 1 and than to 0 after you click again? can you explain what you need in more detail?

Comment: no no if I click a second time it shows me two. It count a number of cliks of each button my problem with ajax code i want to save into server and insert it in my database.

Comment: So you want each click to be saved into a database after you click on a button?

Comment: yeah i want each click of each button be saved into a database.

Comment: i've edited my answer according to the last comment. try with that code please.

Comment: it's hard to help you when you provide so little information. can you tell me if you get an error in the console? error on the server? in your developer console, in networking tab, does it show that call went to the server?

Comment: When I add my ajax code or your code I have no error and not see my clicks like on the picture.

Comment: where don't you see it? in database? or on web page? not displayed in console?

Comment: in my console. Ajax code does not work so it's normal that I can not save in the database.

Comment: I've updated the answer. This should work if your php code is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it dosen't work. What i want is to give the user the right to click or de-click on one or more button for each product and I record everything in a database with the product code and the number of clicks on each button.

Comment: I've changed a code a bit. As I see this, your main problem are the ajax calls. I didn't create the database and test that part, but the code seems ok at a first glance. The main problem was the ajax call, and If you set it up this way ajax calls are sent with information about E1. This way you'll toggle E1 from 0 to 1 and to 0 at each click. Replicate the code for other buttons and see if it sends ajax calls and try to console log the response and see if it works. We can go on from there with other stuff when ajax works.

Comment: When I tested all your code not working at all but when I took just the ajax code it displays clicks for E1.

Comment: Check this code out. If you've set up the database it will work. I strongly recommend you to go trough some more tutorials before continuing since your code has a lot of typographical mistakes. Sites that have good tutorials on php, javascript and sql are: http://www.w3schools.com/ and http://tutorialspoint.com/